# Not able to find audio source element in amazon music web

Tags: html, html5-audio

I have been using Amazon music for a while and I was just playing around in  "Chrome Developer tools".

As far as I know, `audio/video` tag is used for embedding multimedia content. So I was trying to find on `audio` tag but I can't locate one.

I am curious to know how Amazon streams music on the web.

Is it possible to stream audio without any `audio/video` tag on a webpage?

Comment: Yes it's possible. As to how Amazon did, can't tell, but they may well just have used an offscreen audio element, e.g `(()=>new Audio('somefile.mp3').play())()` would create an audio element, that you can't access, but still playing in the page.

Comment: Phew! I thought I could customize it for my need by access the element in the dom. Looks like not possible. Thanks for the help!